# Pyrogram + pyromod how to delete asking msg

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, pyrogram

I'm trying to delete a message of pyromod ask().

Code example:

```
@app.on_message(filters.command("test", prefixes=".") & filters.text)
async def TestPyromod(_,msg):
    asking = await app.ask(msg.chat.id, "enter: ")
    await asking.delete()
```

With this code I remove input, but i need to delete the "enter: ".

Answer (score 0):

```
asking = await app.ask(msg.chat.id, "enter: ")
await asking.request.delete()
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: This method to delete the ask message is not found in the pyromod docs, so i have read the source code of pyromod to know that

Answer (score 0):

with the new pyromod version you would do something like

```
await asking.sent_message.delete()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).